# How to access $Children page controller functions?

Tags: php, function, silverstripe

I'm using **SilverStripe** framework with CMS and I ran into a troubles with accessing children page functions in current page.

Let's say we have `CataloguePage` page type and it has a lot of `ProductPage` page types. In a `ProductPage` there is a function. I want to access this function in `CataloguePage` view.

How can I do that?

This can't do actually what I want, but I think I'm pretty close to solution:

```
<% loop $Children %>
  $MyChildrenPageFunction
<% end_loop %>
```

Any help, please?

Comment: what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I have a function that gets a field from DataObject that belongs to Page and does something with it.
It works perfectly on my Page, but not in it's parent page, using <% loop Children %>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, all methods that modify the child DataObject should be in the DataObject / Page itself, not in the controller. So the easiest would be to move the methods to the DataObject or Page, either by copying it or by making an DataExtension and applying that to the child page type.

```
class MyStuff extends DataExtension {

    public method doSomething() {
        return 'I did something';
    }
}
```

and in your *mysite/_config/config.yml*:

```
ChildPageType: #classname of the page type you want to decorate
  extensions:
    - MyStuff #class name of the extension you want to apply
```

Comment: Actually I moved my function from `class ProductPage_Controller` to `class ProductPage` and it worked like a charm! Really big thanks! It was such a pain in ass.